# Sci-fi short story, aliens warned not to wake last human from cryo sleep

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cryogenics

The last human (a man) is found in a cryo-pod by some aliens, and an older frog-dude warns them all that humans were incredibly dangerous back when and that it should stay frozen. They do wake him, but I don't recall what happens next. I don't think it proves dangerous. I guess all the other humans had killed themselves in a space-war.

It was from a collection of short stories, but I can't recall its title. I think I read it about 7 years ago.

Comment: They were warned not to wake the sleeping creature because it was incredibly dangerous, but they wake it anyway—and it's NOT dangerous? There can't be too many stories with that plot.

Answer (score 4):

Does [The Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_(short_story)) by van Vogt ring a bell? In it, "monsters" come to Earth and revive people to find out what went wrong. They wake one too many...

Artwork from [the original story](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736) had sort of [frog/lizard people](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736#page/n55/mode/2up) with [balloons on their backs](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736#page/n63/mode/2up).

Comment: If it really was that story (hard to tell from the vague description), the OP may well have read it under its alternate title ["Resurrection"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63317).